# Grey page content when side menu is opened

Tags: html, menu, ionic-framework, hamburger-menu

If you look at all the Google apps when you open the side (hamburger) menu the content of the app is greyed.

Here is an example

[image]

Is it possible to do this with `ion-side-menu` in ionic framework? If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is not standard available in Ionic, but if you look at the `$ionicModal` you can see they do use the same technique there.

If you look at the CSS they use for this option, you should add the following to the correct class:

```
opacity: .5;
transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
background-color: #000;
```

You should somehow detect when the side menu is exposed and then apply above CSS to the `<ion-nav-view>`.

I think you could create a directive or so which watches the [$ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/) function and based on result apply or remove the CSS.

Comment: Thanks, it helped figuring out a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Mark Veenstra's answer, here is the result I came with.

In CSS:

```
.opaque-content {
   opacity: .5;
   transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

In the controller I'm watching the open ratio of the side menu and set a flag:

```
$scope.$watch(
   function () {
      return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.getOpenRatio();
   },
   function (ratio) {
      $scope.sidemenuopened = (ratio == 1);
   });
```

In the template I'm using `ng-class` to conditionally apply the class:

```
<ion-side-menus>
   <ion-side-menu-content ng-class="{'opaque-content' : sidemenuopened}">
      <ion-nav-bar>
      </ion-nav-bar>

   </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>
```

This works and makes the page content partially transparent when the side menu is opened.

Answer (score 2):

You only need CSS for this.

When the side menu is opened, there is a CSS class **menu-open** added to the **body** tag.

So just add the following and you will get what you want.

```
body.menu-open ion-side-menu-content {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Marius Bancila's answer, here is my solution.

In CSS: `nothing`

In the controller I'm watching the open ratio of the side menu and set a flag:

```
$scope.$watch(
   function () {
      return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.getOpenRatio();
   },
   function (ratio) {
      $scope.sidemenuopened = (ratio == 1);
   });
```

In the template I used modal backdrop background class instead of your opaque-content which isn't gray at all:

```
<ion-side-menus>
   <ion-side-menu-content>
      <div ng-class="{'modal-backdrop-bg' : sidemenuopened}"></div>
      <ion-nav-bar>
      </ion-nav-bar>

   </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>
```

With this you will have the same effect as Google!